# What is the relation between the set of all accumulation points of a metric space, say $A$, and its closure?

Tags: metric-spaces

> In general, what is the relation between the set of all accumulation points of a
>   a subset of a metric space, say $A$, and its closure ?

For any $a \in A$, if $a \in IntA$, then $a \in Accum(A)$. However, I could not derive the same thing for the boundary of $A$

**Edit:**

These are the definitions that I'm using:

$$\{\text{accumulation points of }A\} = \{ a\in E | \forall \epsilon > 0 \quad (B(a, \epsilon) - \{a\} )\cap A \not = \emptyset\}$$

$$\partial(A) = \{ a \in E | \forall \epsilon >0 , B(a, \epsilon) \cap A \not = \emptyset \quad and \quad B(a, \epsilon) \cap A^c \not = \emptyset  \}$$

$$\{\text{accumulation points of }A\} = int(A) \cup \partial (A)$$

Comment: $cl(A)=A \cup \{\text {set of all accumulation points}\}$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mathmore Yes but how can we prove it ?

Comment: @Mathmore Note that, I edited the question as "$A $ is a subset of a metric space".

Comment: The relation that I mentioned is actually the alternate definition of the closure of a set. What definition you are using for the closure?

Comment: See [Definition of closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)).

Comment: $\partial(A) = \{ a \in E | \forall \epsilon >0 , B(a, \epsilon) \cap A \not = \emptyset \quad and \quad B(a, \epsilon) \cap A^c \not = \emptyset  \}$, where $A \subset E$.And $cl(A) = int(A) \cup \partial (A)$

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is the *[derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics))* of the set $A$, which is denoted by $A'$. In general $A'\subset\overline A$. When we have $A'=A$, we say that $A$ is a [perfect set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set). On the other hand, there are cases in which $A\varsupsetneq A'\varsupsetneq A''\varsupsetneq\cdots$. For instance, if$$A=\left\{\frac1n+\frac1m\,\middle|\,m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right \},$$then$$A'=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\cup\{0\}$$and $A''=\{0\}$ (and, of course, after this all derived sets are equal to $\{0\}$)..

Comment: Actually, I was going to ask "How to prove that p is an accumulation point of A iff $\exists (x_n) \in A$ s.t $\lim x_n = p$" after this question.Therefore, I am going to ask you to prove it, or provide a reference for the proof of it.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Please define “accumulation point”.

Comment: Plus, consider $A = \{ 1/n | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. The only accumulation point of $A$ is $0$, whereas $1$ is in the boundary of $A$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Again, please define “accumulation point”.

Comment: $\{\text{accumulation points of }A\} = \{ a\in E | \forall \epsilon > 0 \quad (B(a, \epsilon) - \{a\} )\cap A \not = \emptyset\}$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Then$$\{\text{accumulation points of }A\}=\overline A$$by definition.

Comment: I have forgot one term in the definition, i.e "- $\{a \}$", but edited now.